# Filebeat Cisco Module for Nexus having errors reading the config file

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk, elastic-beats

I am trying to set up syslogging from a nexus switch to feed into Filebeat's Cisco module that would then feed into Elasticsearch. I tend to get the same error message after enabling the cisco module and running this from powershell `./filebeat.exe setup -e`. The version of Elasticsearch, Kibana and Filebeat are all 8.9.0.

Filebeat is able to connect to Elasticsearch but here is the error I keep getting which seems to terminate the Filebeat service:

```
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-26T09:56:05.655-0700","log.origin":

{"file.name":"cfgfile/reload.go","file.line":270},"message":"Error loading config from file 'C:\Program 

Files\Filebeat-8.9.0-CISCO\modules.d\cisco.yml', **error invalid config: yaml: line 102: did not find expected 

key","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}**
```

Here is the `cisco.yml` file from the modules.d folder:

```
Starts on line 99.

  nexus:
     enabled: true

# Set which input to use between udp (default), tcp or file.  
 var.input: udp
 var.syslog_host: 10.0.0.83
 var.syslog_port: 9004

# Set paths for the log files when file input is used.
# var.paths:

# Toggle output of non-ECS fields (default true).
# var.rsa_fields: true

# Set custom timezone offset.
# "local" (default) for system timezone.
# "+02:00" for GMT+02:00
# var.tz_offset: local`
```

**Line 102 is the "Set which input to use between udp, tcp or file"**. It has been confirmed data is being sent but when I start the Filebeat service with the cisco module enabled, the filebeat service starts for a few seconds and then stops. When I turned off the cisco module and started the Filebeat service, it ran just fine with no issues.

Not sure why I keep getting the error, been stuck on this for a while.

I have reviewed the cisco.yml config file countless time, changed the var.syslog_host to 0.0.0., I changed the protocol from udp to tcp and then changed it back. I tried a slightly newer version(Filebeat 8.9.2) but got the sane error. Please help.

Comment: Yaml is a very picky format, first make sure to remove the initial space on the uncommented `var.*` lines.

Comment: Thank you sir! That fixed my issue. I  appreciate it ! You Da Man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As YAML is a very picky format, you first need to make sure to remove the initial spaces on the uncommented lines.

```
# Set which input to use between udp (default), tcp or file.  
var.input: udp
var.syslog_host: 10.0.0.83
var.syslog_port: 9004
^
|
here
```